# Dropwizard hot deployment

Tags: java, rest, hotdeploy, dropwizard

I'm looking for a simple to use system in Java which creates a REST service for me. So I found dropwizard but as far as I can use google it turns out it lacks hot deployment although jetty is able to do so. When using the maven-shade-plugin it takes at least 10 seconds to build the thing. Also my IDE reports that it cannot use compile on save feature (aka hot deployment) when the shade-plugin is involved.

Can I use hotdeployment somehow? Or what can I use instead?

**Update**: If nothing will fix this I'll probably use a combination of jersey&guice etc which is explained in [this post](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2011/08/15/a-simple-java-web-stack-with-guice-jetty-jersey-and-jackson/)

Comment: Would using a servlet 3.0 container be an option?  I believe it can do what you need just from annotations in your code.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen do you have a simple example where I can see this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use the shade plugin to run your service. You could just compile as a regular jar file and I think that would let you use your IDEs hot deployment features.

Comment: the shaded jar is mostly useful for deployment

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) ? They have JAX-RS support as well...

Answer (score -1):

Not an answer, but I wrote up an article detailing how to use git to push a Dropwizard project to your server and for it to initiate a hot **replacement**. It relies on git hooks and running Maven via a script on the server.

You can find the details about it here: http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2013/02/14/how-to-deploy-dynamic-sites-with-git/

Comment: this is not hot deployment. hot deployment is when you can edit your java files, hit save, your IDE compiles and jetty restarts within 1 second with the updated class file

Comment: That's why I wrote replacement - not deployment. Apologies for the confusion. Edited the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Hmmh ... also this script is suboptimal (I've a better one ;)) as it stops the site and starts compiling afterwards!? It should compile first and only if test passes restart the server!

Comment: The article does state that it is for development purposes and that a production version would be coded differently. If you'd like to post your improved version then I can add it to the article as a suggested approach with full credit to you.