# DropWizard - Hot Deployment, No Restarts, static resources

Tags: java, durandal, dropwizard

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092010/dropwizard-hot-deployment), but not much help.

`<dropwizard.version>0.8.1</dropwizard.version>` is used currently.

Whenever i make changes to `Html` or `Js` or `Java` files (using `Durandal`), we need to build the jar file, and then run the server again.

Are there any settings that i need to put, so as to avoid restarts for at least static resources, and they can be picked on the fly.

Code is `build` using `mvn clean install`,

Below is command i fire, to `run`

```
java -jar target/my.jar server my-dev.yml
```

Any plugin i can add to `POM.xml` ..??

Any changes in `my-dev.yml`..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [SpringLoaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded). It has limitations but worked good enough for me and was easy to integrate with dropwizard. I've never used it with static resources so I don't know if it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intellij you can solve it with starting the main method in your Application class like this:

[image]